# Faster way to transform this XML with XSLT?

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt

I'm a complete noob with XSLT and I've been looking around and I've tried to find an answer for this. The XSLT below works with my small sample file, however the actual xml file is 200 mb and I waited 20 minutes before cancelling it. My question is, is there a quicker way to do this? Is my XSLT sloppy? I am using this in Access because I have no choice.

Here is a sample of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ACES version="3.0">

<App action="A" id="1">
    <BaseVehicle id="119703">2013 Acura MDX                                                                                                 </BaseVehicle>
    <EngineBase id="5816">V6 3.7L (224cid 3664cc) 3.54x3.78in/90.0x96.0mm</EngineBase>
    <FuelType id="5">GAS</FuelType>
    <Qty>1</Qty>
</App>
<App action="A" id="2">
    <BaseVehicle id="119703">2013 Acura MDX                                                                                                 </BaseVehicle>
    <EngineBase id="2147">V6 3.7L (-cid 3664cc) 3.54x3.78in/90.0x96.0mm</EngineBase>
    <FuelType id="5">GAS</FuelType>
    <Qty>1</Qty>
</App>
</ACES>
```

And here is the XSLT I'm using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//ACES/App/BaseVehicle">
    <BaseID><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></BaseID>
    <BaseName><xsl:value-of select="//ACES/App/BaseVehicle"/></BaseName>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//ACES/App/EngineBase">
    <EngineID><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></EngineID>
    <EngineName><xsl:value-of select="//ACES/App/EngineBase"/></EngineName>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//ACES/App/FuelType">
    <FuelID><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></FuelID>
    <FuelName><xsl:value-of select="//ACES/App/FuelType"/></FuelName>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

All I really want are the @id's and the text values. So something like:

```
BaseID   BaseVehicle       EngineID    EngineBase

119703   2013 Acura MDX     5816       V6 3.7L (224cid 3664cc) 3.54x3.78in/90.0x96.0mm
```

*As an example for the first one (I want a list of everything in this order)*

Is there a faster way I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want XML output? then please show expected xml, Or do you want text, then use `<xsl:output method="text"/>`

Comment: Your XML isn't well formed - where are the BaseVehicle end tags?

Comment: @MichaelKay - the ends of BaseVehicle are hiding way off the right. I wonder if that equates to around 20Mb of whitespace ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately someone else makes the file for me, so nothing I can do about it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is taking so long is that every time you hit a BaseVehicle, for example, you process every BaseVehicle in the document:

```
<xsl:template match="//ACES/App/BaseVehicle">
    <BaseID><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></BaseID>
    <BaseName><xsl:value-of select="//ACES/App/BaseVehicle"/></BaseName>
</xsl:template>
```

That should almost certainly be written:

```
<xsl:template match="BaseVehicle">
    <BaseID><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></BaseID>
    <BaseName><xsl:value-of select="."/></BaseName>
</xsl:template>
```

(Actually, if you're using an XSLT 1.0 processor, then `select="//ACES/App/BaseVehicle"` will only output the value of the first BaseVehicle, which may be very fast or very slow depending how smart your XSLT processor is. But it doesn't really matter how long it takes, because it will give the wrong output.)

When corrected, I would expect this stylesheet to run in 10 seconds or so using Saxon.

Comment: This worked. Took about 10 minutes in Access unfortunately, but I can deal with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you write will try to output all e.g. `BaseVehicle`'s text content, you want only the one of the current context node.

I suggest to use

```
<xsl:template match="App">
    <BaseID><xsl:value-of select="BaseVehicle/@id"/></BaseID>
    <BaseName><xsl:value-of select="BaseVehicle"/></BaseName>
    <EngineID><xsl:value-of select="EngineBase/@id"/></EngineId>
    <EngineName><xsl:value-of select="EngineBase"/></EngineName>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say I want a list of every BaseID, for example, not just the first one.

Comment: Have you tried the code? It gives one for every App. You certainly don't want **all** and for the next `App` again **all** ?!?

Comment: Yes, I tried it and access is only returning 1 row of data for that when I use it to transform. Michael Kay's suggestion worked for me.